# PyGtk - Activating a combo box

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, pygtk

If I have a combo box in pyGTK and would like to set a list of strings and then on clicking on one activate a command how would I do it?

At the moment I have:

```
    self.combo_key = gtk.Combo()
    self.combo_key.set_popdown_strings(self.keys)
    self.combo_key.entry.set_text(db.keys()[0])
    self.combo_key.entry.connect("activate", self.key_sel)
```

But `"activate"` only calls after selection, and then by pressing enter. I'm also getting a deprecation warning for `gtk.Combo()` but cannot find any help on using `gtk.ComboBoxEntry()`

Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `gtk.ComboBox` instead of `gtk.Combo`, since the latter is deprecated in favor of the former.  To initialise, you can you code like:

```
liststore = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
for key in self.keys:
    liststore.append((key,))
combobox = gtk.ComboBox(liststore)
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
combobox.pack_start(cell, True)
combobox.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
```

Now you connect to the `changed` signal of the `combobox` and use its `get_active()` method to ask for the item that was selected.

As you might guess from this explanation, the ComboBox isn't exactly made for this purpose.  You probably want to use `gtk.Menu`.